# Typing NamedTuple as a class to include argument hints in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, namedtuple, python-typing

EDIT: Type[X] does type hint to the class itself. The repl now has an example of that, too. PyCharm just doesn't use the `__init__` information within the class to type hint an initialization elsewhere. If anyone knows why that is, I'll accept that answer. The below question is now just for context:

Let's say I have the following code:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple, Type

class SubTuple(NamedTuple):
  a: str
  b: int

def get_tuple_type() -> Type[SubTuple]:
  return SubTuple

test_tuple = get_tuple_type()
test_tuple_instance = test_tuple('test', 1)
```

Is there a way to type hint so that PyCharm will give me argument hints? Right now it gives me this:

[image]

which is rather useless. Hilariously, it does know the arguments, because when I type:

```py
test_tuple.
```

it recommends all of the fields in the `SubTuple`. It just won't recommend them to me when I go to create an instance of the thing.

Also, https://repl.it/repls/BurdensomeInnocentKnowledge just so that you can see that the above code actually does work. The repl IDE also has no idea what to do with this thing, and is recommending that I call .a and .b on the class itself, which leads me to believe this might just be a general issue with what I'm trying to do in Python?

EDIT: I'm using Python 3.7; updated code to include what I've tried. It has the same result. Will update the repl, too.

Comment: Saw this within the `[python]` tag, so not a PyCharm expert by any means. However, perhaps you could try to define the functions return signature as so: `def get_tuple_type() -> SubTuple:`. When you did `a: str`, you defined the class variables signature. PyCharm might pick up if you define the functions return sig.

Comment: Does `get_tuple_type` always return the same class?

Comment: @FelipeFaria Thanks, you reminded me I didn't include what I had already tried. `-> SubTuple` makes it expect an instance. I tried `Type[SubTuple]`, which I think just makes it expect an instance of a subclass, but not positive.

Comment: @IainShelvington It does, yes

Comment: Then why do you need the function at all? Just use `SubTuple`

Comment: Better yet use a dataclass

Comment: @IainShelvington: I provided a minimally viable example, as per StackOverflow's guidelines. This is a sub-problem in my actual code. I will give the dataclass a shot though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in PyCharm's static type checker, there are a few open bugs about [`NamedTuple` on JetBrains bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=namedtuple%20type%20hint). The most up-to-date thread on the `NamedTuple` datatype is [PY-18246](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18246). Fixes have been rolled out during 2020 but this specific case of correctly inferring the `NamedTuple` members after [typing a class object](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects) has neither been reported nor solved.

The warning has also changed, if you try the same code with PyCharm 2020.3.3 Pro you'll get a different hint.

[image: screenshot of warning in editor]

I tried checking the code with Mypy and it works correctly without any warnings. If you try causing an error by changing the types:

```py
variable = test_tuple(1, 'test')
```

[Mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) warns and correctly hints you about it:

```
error: Argument 1 to "SubTuple" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
error: Argument 2 to "SubTuple" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

> Is there a way to type hint so that PyCharm will give me argument hints?

You are already type hinting correctly as PEP 484 recommends. If you use the Mypy static type checker it works, as for PyCharm it's a matter of waiting for a bug fix. There's nothing wrong with your type hinting and it shouldn't be changed in this case.